# creating multiline textbox using Html.Helper function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a multiline Textbox using ASP.NET MVC with the following code.

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Body", null, new { TextBoxMode = "MultiLine", Columns = "55px", Rows = "10px" })%>
```

It just shows up a single line fixed sized textbox.

on the other hand

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Body" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="55" Rows="10"></asp:TextBox>
```

renders the right view, but in the controller's post method with formCollection named form

```
form["Body"];
```

returns a null value.

Comment: Just noticed that on your first example, you have Columns = "55px". Is that a typo or it's like that in the code? See if taking that out fixes your problem :) I am not sure if it will so that's why this is just a comment...

Comment: I would still go down the dataannotations route, unless this is an MVC1 project

Answer (score 107, accepted):

A multiline textbox in html is `<textarea>`:

```
<%= Html.TextArea("Body", null, new { cols = "55", rows = "10" }) %>
```

or:

```
<%= Html.TextArea("Body", null, 10, 55, null) %>
```

or even better:

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Body, 10, 55, null) %>
```

And yet another possibility is to decorate your view model property with the [`[DataType]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679282.aspx) attribute:

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Body { get; set; }
```

and in your view:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Body) %>
```

and set the width and height through CSS.

Comment: I usually use EditorFor, and set height etc with Css. Seems cleaner

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works! I also just figured out that the attribute for columns is cols...

Comment: @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments, 5, 2, null) worked for the rows but the columns appears to be ignored?

Comment: with class like `new { @class = "form-control" }` check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6218024/2218697)

Answer (score 6):

MVC4 you should use:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Body, 10, 15, null)
```

Comment: with class like `new { @class = "form-control" }` check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6218024/2218697)

Answer (score 4):

This allows to multi-line, set custom width and height and setting place holder.
For validation used StringLength or RegularExpression in Model.cs

**Razor View Syntax**

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.property, new { style = "width: 420px; height: 100px;", placeholder = "Placeholder here.." })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Html.EditorFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor.aspx) Is what you're looking for. That's only for MVC2 and up though. Does that help?

If you're using DataAnnotations and decorate your property with the `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]`
 Attribute, MVC should scaffold out the required html for you.

Comment: There is no `MultilineText` attribute. Do you mean `DataType` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

In Entity layer:

```
[MaxLength(500)]
public string Body { get; set; }
```

And in view:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body, new { rows = 10, cols = 50 })
```

Answer (score 0):

VB.net solution:

@Html.TextAreaFor(Function(Model) Model.Body, 3, 55, Nothing)