# Environment.NewLine Does Not Put Each entry On New Row

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have the following code which is to display an address but it does not seem to put each address row on a new line and cant figure out why

```
var selectedOrigoScheme = origoCedingSchemes.Where(x => x.complyingFundId.ToString() == SelectedSchemeId).ToList();
string origoName = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedOrigoScheme[0].origoName) ? selectedOrigoScheme[0].origoName + Environment.NewLine : "";
string propertyName = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedOrigoScheme[0].propertyName) ? selectedOrigoScheme[0].propertyName + Environment.NewLine : "";
string streetNumber = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedOrigoScheme[0].streetNumber) ? selectedOrigoScheme[0].streetNumber + Environment.NewLine : "";
string street = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedOrigoScheme[0].street) ? selectedOrigoScheme[0].street + Environment.NewLine : "";
string street2 = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedOrigoScheme[0].street2) ? selectedOrigoScheme[0].street2 + Environment.NewLine : "";
string suburb = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedOrigoScheme[0].suburb) ? selectedOrigoScheme[0].suburb + Environment.NewLine : "";
string district = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedOrigoScheme[0].district) ? selectedOrigoScheme[0].district + Environment.NewLine : "";
string postcode = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedOrigoScheme[0].postcode) ? selectedOrigoScheme[0].postcode + Environment.NewLine : "";
string Origoaddress = origoName + propertyName + streetNumber + street + street2 + suburb + district + postcode;
viewData["Origoaddress"] = Origoaddress;
```

When I debug I get the following result:

*Aviva\r\nNorwich Business Capture Centre\r\nPO Box 520\r\nNorwich\r\nNR1 3WG \r\n*

If I look at the result in text visualizer it displays correctly:

*Aviva*

*Norwich Business Capture Centre*

*PO Box 520*

*Norwich*

*NR1 3WG*

---

But if I look at it using HTML visualizer it displays as:

Aviva Norwich Business Capture Centre PO Box 520 Norwich NR1 3WG

---

Which is how its showing in my address field on the website.

What am I doing wrong as I cant see the issue.

**HTML**

```
<%=Html.TextBox("Origoaddress", ViewData["Origoaddress"].ToString())%>
```

Comment: doesn't html ignore white space?  That's why people feel the need to use <br> to force a line break.

Comment: html viewers don't care about new line characters. If you want a new line in rendered html, you need to add something like a `<br/>` tag.

Comment: Also potentially try TextArea instead of TextBox as that should support multiple lines and might work as you intend-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021935/creating-multiline-textbox-using-html-helper-function

Comment: @C.Knight it was because I was using a TextBox and not a TextArea.  Got a little code blind lol.  Could you add this as an the answer so I can accept it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html ignores white spaces so is ignoring the line breaks you have added.  If you were working in pure html you'd need to use < br>.  Html.TextBox only supports single line strings so doesn't add line breaks that Html will understand.

In order to use multiple lines you will probably need to use TextArea.  See [creating multiline textbox using Html.Helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021935/creating-multiline-textbox-using-html-helper-function)
for further details.